# How to make environment variable set by job dsl avaiable in downstream jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

The job seeder creates a pipeline job and sets environment variable using job dsl as shown below, this pipeline job triggers another job(say job2) which in turn triggers another job(say job3). I want the environment variable set in seed job to be accessed in the triggered jobs.

```
pipelineJob("job1"){
  description("job1..")
  concurrentBuild(false)
  environmentVariables(
         globalEnv + [TEMP_ENV1               : 'true',
                      TEMP_ENV2               : 'true'
                     ]
   )
  definition {
      cps {
         script(
               """
job1script()
"""
         )
      }
   }
}
```

I want to access TEMP_ENV1 and TEMP_ENV2 in job3, but both are null in this job. i have a check in script which job3 executes it and it fails, e.g.
 `if (env.TEMP_ENV1) { }`

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke the job using the build step (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) and pass these along as parameters:

```
build(
    job: "myjob2", 
    parameters: [
        string(name: 'TEMP_ENV1', defaultValue: TEMP_ENV1, description: 'Temp env var 1')
    ], 
    propagate: false
)
```

Comment: I do aware of it but what if there are multiple jobs or chain of jobs, also, these jobs are already parameterized jobs and I don't want to introduce new parameters as it has nothing to do with users, it's more of for internal handling.

Comment: Perhaps the jobs need to call out to a centralised store of information? So you update value in job 1 and job 2 reads it?